# Как вытащить данные из базы

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят есть вот база, и в нем таблица ocmc_t_item, как мне вытащить из этой таблицы количество записей: за последнее неделю, за последний месяц и общее количество
[image: Ребят есть вот база, и в нем таблица ocmc_t_item, как мне вытащить из этой таблицы количество записей: за последнее неделю, за последний месяц и общее количество]

Comment: Нужно разобраться, есть ли в таблице столбец с датой создания записи. Если есть, то делать выборку с условием по этому столбцу.

Comment: Что подразумевается под последней неделей? Последние 7 дней? Или же данные за период с понедельника по воскресенье последней недели? Аналогично и с месяцем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
  SELECT * FROM `ocmc_t_item` WHERE dt_pub_date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Если же поле имеет формат UnixTime то

```
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Где 1 MONTH можете указывать например, 7 day, 30 day и так далее, соответственно.

Для того что бы сделать запрос к базе данных из кода РНР вам нужно сделать следующее в коде РНР пишете:

```
<?php
  $config = array(
  'db' => array (
  'server' => 'имя вашего сервера, например, localhost',
  'username' => 'имя пользователя в вашей БД, например root',
  'password' => 'пароль к вашей БД если есть, если нету, ничего не вводите',
  'name' => 'имя вашей БД',
```

Далее

```
  $connection = mysqli_connect(
  $config['db']['server'],
  $config['db']['username'],
  $config['db']['password'],
  $config['db']['name'],
  );

  if($connection == false) {
  echo 'Не удалось подключаться к базе данных<br>';
  echo mysqli_conntect_error();
  exit();
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `ocmc_t_item` WHERE dt_pub_date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH")

  ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,Сделал как вы сказали не помогло, я выше сделал скрин базы и там есть поле с датами, не помогло

Comment: Отредактировал сообщение, я указал ocmc_t_item в качестве вашей таблицы, если у вашей таблицы другое имя, введи именно его туда, и повторите запрос.

Comment: Я добавли на страницу, там все как есть так и выходит, то-есть прям все что пишу в коде, выходит на страницу

Comment: Откройте вашу таблицу в PhpMyAdmin, зайдите в раздел SQL и сделайте там этот запрос SELECT * FROM `ocmc_t_item` WHERE dt_pub_date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), если там запрос сработает, то значит проблема в том, что у вас в РНР или каковый там язык используете запрос к БД прописан неправильно

Comment: сделал запрос в phpmyadmin вышла такая ошибка  #1146 - Table 'bakuelan_oscl529.ocmc_t_item' doesn't exist

Comment: В ошибке сказано, что таблицы к которой вы обращаетесь не существует. В скриншоте который вы приводите имя таблицы osmc_t_item, а то что вы сделали запрос там имя таблицы bakuelan_oscl529.ocmc_t_item, либо укажите  имена ваших таблиц, либо вам помочь не получится, и более того, вы сами запутаетесь.

Comment: се запрос вышел: Отображение строк 0 - 17 (18 всего, Запрос занял 0.0011 сек.) [dt_pub_date: 2017-04-28 15:29:19 - 2017-04-22 11:58:13] и как мне это на сайте выташить количество тех самых строк? или количество объявлений за этот промежуток

Comment: Какой язык программирования вы используете?

Comment: ну вроде php, там почти все функции пишется <?php

Comment: Обновил ответ с кодом

Comment: Спасибо большое, потом проверю и отпишусь

Comment: Благодарностей не нужно, если все работает отметьте зеленой галочкой слева от сообщения, где ответ с кодом.

Comment: Я проверил, и после того как пишу это, пишу данные. То част сайта не отображается просто, та часть которая идет после кода

Comment: Найдите в вашем коде строки похожие на  = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `ocmc_t_item` WHERE dt_pub_date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH") и замените их на этот код тогда

Answer (score 1):

Если в таблице нет поля даты-времени - задача нерешаема. А если есть, то

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total
     , SUM(datetime_field > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) lastweek
     , SUM(datetime_field > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) lastmonth
FROM ocmc_t_item;
```

Comment: Увы не помогло. я внизу скинул скрин базы, где есть вроде поле с датами

Comment: @FlitzCollins что конкретно не помогло? Возникает ошибка?

Comment: @vitaly-kolyada Я добавли на страницу, там все как есть так и выходит, то-есть прям все что пишу в коде, выходит на страницу

Comment: Показывайте структуру таблицы и выполнение запроса, построенного на основе совета. И никаких скриншотов!!! только текст - копию с консоли.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такое вот поле
я добавил код который вы сказали и на сайте вышло так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total ,
    SUM(dt_pub_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) lastweek , 
    SUM(dt_pub_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) lastmonth
FROM ocmc_t_item;
```